# swift how to update viewModel parameter while init

Tags: swift, struct, parameters, viewmodel

I have encountered the problem "Cannot assign to property: 'self' is an immutable capture".  How can i call API to check status and update "getUpdateSuccess" parameter

```
struct HomepageViewModel {

  var getUpdateSuccess: Bool = false

  init() {

       getStatusUpdated.execute().done {
            [self] isUpdated in

            // Cannot assign to property: 'self' is an immutable capture
            self.getUpdateSuccess = isUpdated
        }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to “reference” `self` later (e.g., update the same instance later), `self` should be a reference type, not a value type.

So you can solve this by making the view model a `class` (a reference type) rather than a `struct` (a value type).

“Model” objects are good candidates for value types, but “view models” are generally reference types. See [Value and Reference Types](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10) for a discussion of when you might use a value type and when you might use a reference type. For a general discussion, see [The Swift Programming Language: Structures and Classes](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html).

---

By the way, the closure’s capture list syntax (the stuff in between the `[` and the `]`) has different practical implications if the captured variable is a reference type vs when it is a value type.

With a value type, the capture list makes sure you have a copy of the value:

```swift
struct Person {…}

var person = Person(…)
foo { [person] in 
    // this code will be dealing with a safe copy of the original `Person`
}

// maybe you’ll mutate the original `Person` instance here,
// but the above closure will have a copy of the original one
```

Contrast that with a reference type, where the capture list makes sure you have a strong reference to the reference type:

```
class ViewModel {
    func bar() {
        baz { [self] in
            // this has a strong reference to this view model instance, not a copy of the instance
        }
    }
}

let viewModel = ViewModel(…)
viewModel.bar()   // any updates that bar does asynchronously, will update this instance of the view model, not a copy of it
```

As an aside, with reference types, you will often see a capture list with the `weak` keyword, e.g., `[weak self]`, if you want a “weak” reference to the class rather than a strong reference. This is common if you need to prevent a “strong reference cycle” (a topic beyond the scope of this conversation). This is discussed in [The Swift Programming Language: Strong Reference Cycles for Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ID56).

But, whether a strong reference or weak reference, you are not dealing with a copy of the object, but rather a “reference” to the same original instance.